# Multiple Resistors for Rf in Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, resistance

Is it allowable to combine the R6 and Rx resistors shown below? The resistors R6 and Rx are in series, and I need to calculate the gain. Given R6=2kOhm and Rx=2kOhm, then can Rf be taken as 4kOhm?

[image]

Comment: My calculator shows that 2k + 2k= 4K the same and your calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you are using the feedback equations you can consider the resistors in series to be the same resistance.